# How to control the report output in Cognos 10.1?

Tags: report, cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

Currently I'm working Cognos 10.1 report studio.

The requirement is that the output should be in such a way that the crosstab should appear in a default size in all the pages eventhough the outputs differ. **The crosstab size should be same in all the pages but the font size could differ.**

Eg: 
Crosstab has the ***product line in row; product in column; revenue in diagonal***. Page set has been applied for the crosstab based on the product line. i.e. Each product line would appear in a separate page.

---

The number of products for each product line differs. The crosstab should be in same size in all the pages but the font size could differ.

---

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to force a row in your result set for each Row/Column combination. Do this by outer joining your result set against two queries: one of distinct row values, one of distinct columns. Next you'd have to give each cell a fixed width so that it is not dynamically formmated in HTML.